# Graphics quality degrades when logging in

Tags: graphics, lubuntu

This is weird. When I'm on the login screen the graphics quality is very good, then background is smooth. But after logging in the graphics turns bad that I can see the layer change of colors. What could be the problem?

Comment: What graphic cards do you have? What drivers are installed?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your user's defined screen resolution is not set correctly. The screen resolution may be different between the user session and the login screen.

Have you tried changing your screen resolution in `System Settings > Displays` ?

Comment: Yes I already set it to the maximum I can get.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your resolution to something low and then back to the maximum. I've seen this clear odd resolution issues in the past.

Answer (score 0):

My fault I haven't see that you are using lubuntu (that comes by default with lxde)

Here are some suggestions:

- Find out your supported/max resolutions supported by your graphic card/monitor with `xrandr -q` and change it up to max.

*Example*: `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1920x1080`

- [Disable](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1780682) GPU acceleration in Xorg by adding the option `"NoAccel"`, note that you need (most probably) to first [create](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1492) an Xorg configuration.

In order to get better help from the community you should include the following from your system:

- `lspci`
- `xrandr -q`

**Note:** Since you are having graphics issues, if you are not being able to "see" a terminal properly you could switch to a tty (terminal) by using below keys combination

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: It doesn't have that option, only `Lubuntu Netbook`